# jquery tabs truncating content on iPad Safari

Tags: ipad, jquery-ui-tabs

When the iPad first came out I modified my website to use jQuery tabs and everything was working on all browsers including iPad Safari. But on the latest iPad Safari, the jQuery tabs are cutting off the content. [EDIT: when I wrote "latest" only the iPad1 was available; the website with tabs works fine on iPad2! Problem occurs only on iPad1. arrgh]  Other browsers continue to work fine. The amount of content varies considerably from tab to tab and the text content in individual tabs can be quite long given the document-centric nature of the website.  I tried googling

```
   jQuery tabs iPad site: stackoverflow.com
```

but couldn't find anything relating to this particular problem, though [this SO discussion from 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436587/jquery-ui-tabs-automatic-height), where the tab heights are explicitly set to the size required by the tab with the greatest height, might be a workaround. Thanks for any suggestions/links to further reading.

Comment: I have gotten around the content-truncation problem on iPad1 by using jQuery UI ajax-tabs instead: rather than getting its content from a DIV within the same document, the tab uses an external 'document' for its content--to be precise, not a document but merely a large chunk of HTML markup -- without DOCTYPE, HEAD, and BODY sections.

Answer (score 1):

Have you come across the [meta tags specifics to iOS Safaris](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safarihtmlref/articles/metatags.html)? I'm guessing the viewport meta tag may help resolve this issue, e.g.

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "height = device-height, initial-scale = 1.0">
```

Comment: The meta-tag doesn't have the desired effect. What used to work no longer works, and it is not my code that has changed.

Comment: It would probably help if you could post a bit of code and/or a screen shot of the truncated content.

Comment: the code is painfully simple--just the standard jQuery tab declaration using LI elements. And as I said, it works EVERYWHERE but the current version of iPad Safari. It's not my code.  It's some vagary of iPad Safari when the document is large and the content-length of the individual DIVS (tabs) varies considerably. As for the truncation, just imagine a glossary of words running from A to Z that cuts off at the letter H.