# jquery ui tabs, create tab depending on value in database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

i am using jquery-ui tabs to load 3 different views to user, however the problem is that user is not allowed to see all the 3 views all the time. so my question is how to dynamically remove tab if it doesn't contain any content. also another problem is that the tab height is not expanding to fit content.

**php:**

```
 echo '<div id="tabs">';
             echo '<ul><li><a href="#tabs-1">Author</a></li>';
             echo '<li><a href="#tabs-2">Organizer</a></li>';
              echo '<li><a href="#tabs-3">Reviewer</a></li></ul>';
            while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_role)) {
                $role = $r['role'];
                if ($role == 'author') {
                    echo "<div id='tabs-1'>";
                    AuthorView($member_id, $conference_id, $start, $end, $today);
                    echo "</div>";
                } else if ($role == 'organizer') {
                    echo "<div id='tabs-2'>";
                    OrganizerView($conference_id, $end);
                    echo "</div>";
                } else if ($role == 'reviewer') {
                    echo "<div id='tabs-3'>";
                    ReviewerView($member_id, $conference_id, $start, $end, $today);
                    echo "</div>";
                }
            }
            echo "</div>";
```

PS: AuthorView, ReviewerView, OrganizerView are php functions which creates each of the views

Answer (score 0):

For the problem about tab height not fitting content, have a look at this post :

[jQuery UI Tabs - Automatic Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436587/jquery-ui-tabs-automatic-height)

And why dont you make a global function that will hide or not the tabs depending on a return of XxxxView functions ?